# Reference in small font, italic at the bottom

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am trying to have my reference appear on the bottom of the slide (not as footnotes), and I hope someone can help me solve this.

I am using `beamer` and `biblatex`, and here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Alpha}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{\vfill\tiny\itshape}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace{\fill}\textbf{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test1}
Test
\vfill
\fullcite{A01}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliography}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like to have the references appear using overlay and all of them only being at the bottom with tiny fontsize/italic.

I tried to achieve this by using only and `\vfill`, but `\vfill` does not seem to put them at the bottom.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and thank you for providing a MWE. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To align something at the bottom of the page you can use the example of the title page in the beamer manual at page 61. It suggests `\vskip0pt plus 1filll`

<sub>I changed the definition of `footline` related to `beamer` commands`</sub>

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Alpha}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{\tiny\itshape}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \hrulefill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test1}
\vskip0pt plus 1filll

Test

\vskip0pt plus 1filll

\fullcite{A01}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliography}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```